# Import csv data from localhost emacs SQLi error MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/home/frederic/cowtest.csv"
    INTO TABLE cow_db1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
    ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES (state_abb, c_code, state_name);
```

I get: `ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

I connected mysql with `M-x sql-mysql` and

> User = root
>   Password = .....
>   Database =
>   Server = localhost

But running directly from the shell after

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p --local-infile
```

does not return the error but

```
Query OK, 243 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 243  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I tried with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` instead (has recommended in other solution) and then it returns `ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/frederic/cowtest.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)`

So it is likely that things goes unspecified about SQLi extension, and the  `--local-infile` specification.

Many thanks
frederic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems variable  "local_infile" is turned off before loading and if you specify "--local-infile" turns on this variable.

You can use following steps to load file

> login mysql using mysql -uroot -p
>   set global local_infile to value 1
>   Then try load data local infile

Hope it helps

Comment: well I was considering more of an emacs way of doing so, but i'll do that way defining in the my.cnf defining the value local_infile = 1 for [mysql] and [mysqld]